# Powershell - Compare Source and Target directories for .txt files. Copy all files that are not already in target to target AND a third directory

Tags: powershell

Need to compare source directory `$source` to `$dest` to see what `.wav` files are in source but not target.  I want to copy those files that are not in target to the target AND to a third directory `$sharefolder`. Here is what I have so far. It appears that the `copy-item` is putting all of the differences into one copy string:

```
$sharefolder = '\\isilon1\blob\partial_dictation'
$comparefolder = '\\isilon1\blob\partial_dictation_compare'
$source = Get-childitem \\isilon1\blob\dcbld\pv -filter *.wav -recurse
$dest = Get-ChildItem \\isilon1\blob\Partial_Dictation_Compare -filter *.wav -recurse
$diff = Compare-Object $dest $source -passthru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -EQ "=>"} | % {$_.FullName}
ForEach-Object { 
    Copy-Item "$diff" "$comparefolder" -WhatIf
    Copy-Item "$diff" "$sharefolder" -WhatIf
}
```

This is what I get if I `echo $diff ;`

```
\\isilon1\blob\dcbld\pv\-D\CB\LD\-9\94\1.wav
\\isilon1\blob\dcbld\pv\-D\CB\LD\-9\94\2.wav
```

This is correct as these files are not in the destination.  When the copy-item runs, it gives this:

> Copy-Item : Cannot find path '\isilon1\blob\dcbld\pv-D\CB\LD-9\94\1.wav   \isilon1\blob\dcbld\pv-D\CB\LD-9\94\2.wav' because it does not exist.

I am coming from Unix so this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

That's not quite how `ForEach-Object` works.  You need to pipe objects to it, and it will iterate through them for you.  You used it correctly the line above (`%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`).

```
$diff | ForEach-Object { 
    Copy-Item "$_" "$comparefolder" -WhatIf
    Copy-Item "$_" "$sharefolder" -WhatIf
}
```

See `Get-Help ForEach-Object`.

You could also use the `foreach` *statement*, which does a similar thing but isn't a cmdlet:

```
foreach ($file in $diff) {
    Copy-Item "$file" "$comparefolder" -WhatIf
    Copy-Item "$file" "$sharefolder" -WhatIf
}
```

See `Get-Help about_foreach`.

They function slightly differently and have their own benefits -- `foreach` being faster for small collections, and `ForEach-Object` accepting input from a pipe and being capable of streaming objects as soon as they enter the pipe -- but here they're basically identical.

Beware that `Compare-Object` just compares the *name* without path of file and directory objects, as far as I'm aware.  Like it doesn't look at the file size or date, let alone content.  That might be just fine for your needs, but it throws people, IMX.

Comment: Thank you so much Bacon Bits...can you explain what the $_ represents

Comment: `$_` is a special variable (See `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables`, although there's not much there for this one).  It means "the current object in the pipeline".  It's used mostly with `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object`, but those are very common cmdlets.